# PHP Populate Text Box from DropDown Selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to populate two text fields after a user makes a choice on a drop down.
the code below works but is obviously a manual effort in the function.
I need the values for form.accounts and form.client to come from the query the select box is using.
Any ideas.
Should this be jquery - not really familiar with it.

```
<?php                          
$db = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "centrum");

$sql = "SELECT
accounts_client_accounts.accounts_client_account_id,
accounts_client_accounts.accounts,
accounts_client.client
FROM
accounts_client_accounts
INNER JOIN accounts_client ON accounts_client_accounts.accounts_client_id =      accounts_client.accounts_client_id
ORDER BY accounts_client_account_id
";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}?>

<form class="form-ui">
<span class="form-elements reqField">
  <select class="dropdown" onchange="populateData(this)">
   <option value="0">Choose Account</option>
 <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

  echo "<option value='". $row['accounts_client_account_id']."'>".$row['accounts'];
  }
  ?>
  </select>
</span>
<span class="form-elements">
  <input name="accounts" type="text" class="text" value="" />
</span>

<span class="form-elements reqField">
  <input name="client" type="text" class="text" value="" />
</span>
</form>
<script>
function populateData(sel){
    var form = sel.form,
        value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    switch(value){
        case '1':
            form.accounts.value = 'Account1';
            form.client.value = 'Client1';
        break;
        case '2':
            form.accounts.value = 'Account2';
            form.client.value = 'Client2';
        break;
        case '3':
         form.accounts.value = 'Account3';
            form.client.value = 'Client3';
        break;
        default:
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes for the drop down options and populate the fields` values form them. 
Here is the code:

```
<form class="form-ui">
<span class="form-elements reqField">
  <select class="dropdown" onchange="populateData(this)">
   <option value="0">Choose Account</option>
 <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

  echo "<option data-account=".$row['accounts']." data-client=".$row['client']." value='". $row['accounts_client_account_id']."'>".$row['accounts'];
  }
  ?>
  </select>
</span>
<span class="form-elements">
  <input name="accounts" type="text" class="text" value="" />
</span>

<span class="form-elements reqField">
  <input name="client" type="text" class="text" value="" />
</span>
</form>
<script>
function populateData(sel){
    var account = $(this).find(':selected').data('account'),
        client = $(this).find(':selected').data('client');

        form.accounts.value = account;
        form.client.value = client;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks - looks like it will do what I need - but it errors on the function: there is an extra } in it.
what needs to go above form.accounts.value = account; to make this work?